# Free-services.. Un-paid creative work

Tags: sound-design, work, networking, gameaudio

Good Afternoon,

Just signed up as I'm on a quest to start being more active in the sound design community. I am looking for indy/mod teams to work with on film/animation/games. I am wondering whether you know any websites where communities hang out or work may be going? I have signed up to vimeo and contacted some animators and makers directly but if anyone knows of any 'message board' type websites where adverts may be that would be really helpful.

Glad to be part of the site.

Thank you

Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.wreckamovie.com/

http://www.moddb.com/forum/board/recruiting-resumes

Comment: http://forums.cgsociety.org/